# Evaulate $ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n\left[x^k\right]}{ x^n }$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I tried using Squeeze theorem :

$$x\le[x]\lt x+1$$

$$x^2\le[x^2]\lt x^2+1 $$

$$\vdots$$

$$x^n\le[x^n]\lt x^n+1$$

Therefore :

$$\frac{x+x^2+\cdots+x^n}{x^n}\le\frac{[x]+[x^2]+\cdots+[x^n]}{ x^{n} }\lt \frac{x+x^2+\cdots+x^n}{x^n}+\frac{n}{x^n}$$

$${ \underbrace{\frac{x \times (1-x^n)}{x^n(1-x)}}_{L_1} } \le\frac{[x]+[x^2]+\cdots+[x^n]}{ x^{n} }\lt \underbrace{\frac{x \times (1-x^n)}{x^n(1-x)} + \frac{n}{x^n}}_{L_2} $$

$L_1=\cfrac{x- x^{n+1}}{x^n-x^{n+1}} \times \cfrac{x^{-n}}{x^{-n}}= \cfrac{x^{1-n}-x}{1-x}$  and  $L_2=L_1 + \cfrac{n}{x^n}$

For ${ \left| x \right| } \gt 1$ , ${ \lim_{n\to\infty} L_1 }={ \lim_{n\to\infty} L_2 }=\frac{x}{x-1}$

Hence we conclude that: ${ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{[x]+[x^2]+\cdots+[x^n]}{ x^{n} } }= \frac{x}{x-1}$ for  ${ \left| x \right| } \gt 1$

And it is obvious  ${ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{[x]+[x^2]+\cdots+[x^n]}{ x^{n} } }= n$ for $x=1$ .

But I don't know how to evaluate the limit for $-1\lt x \lt 0$ and $0 \lt x \lt 1$ and $x=-1$

Comment: observe that the sum is less than $|nx|$ in those cases to get the answer.

Comment: The limit is $\infty$ for $x=1$ am I right?

Comment: @astro Sorry I don't understand your point Can you explain it more please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

- For $0<x<1$, $[x^n]=0$ for all $n\geq1$
- For $-1<x<0$, $[x^n]=-1$ if $n$ is odd and $0$ otherwise.
- For $x=1$ the expression is $n$
- For $x=-1$ the expression is $0$ if $n$ is even and $1$ of $n$ is odd.